# What does the "radmmamddd data" command do?

Tags: bash, shell

In this code:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
  
for i in {1..500}
do
   echo "radmmamddd data" >> ~/testfile
   sync
done
```

What is the purpose of the command `radmmamddd data`?

Comment: That is just an arbitrary string to populate the `~/testfile` 5000x,  it is not a command, there is an `echo` in front of it...

Answer (score 1):

It merely appends the text "radmmamddd data" to a file named "testfile" in the user's home directory 500 times, meaning the file will have 500 lines with the above text (assuming it was empty before running the command). The trailing `sync` simply makes sure the changes are written to disk by clearing the cache.
However, both the `>>` and the `sync` are misplaced here. By putting it *in* the `for` loop, both calls will be made 500 times. It would be wiser putting it only once *after* the loop, like this:

```
for i in {1..500}; do
  echo "radmmamddd data"
done >> ~/testfile
sync
```

Comment: The code probably was meant to put the string in the file 500 times.  Edit your answer and it would be good.  Three points.  First radmmamddd is a string not a command.  Second >> appends the string to the file.  Third sync makes sure the change is written.

Comment: Hi  Jeter-work,
Thanks for your support